# Dropping the first three blocks on the top

Tags: jenga

When playing Jenga, if you drop the first three blocks on the top, does that count as you losing or you can continue the game?

Comment: Cleaned up the question some, but "dropping the first three blocks on the top" could use some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It counts as losing.

From [the rules](http://jenga.com/about.php):

> The game ends when the tower falls -- completely **or if any block falls from the tower** (other than the block a player moves on a turn).